# What is bound array in Overlaying an image map type google map

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I am new to this map type. it has below code.

```
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 18,
          center: {lat: 37.783, lng: -122.403}
        });

        var bounds = {
          17: [[20969, 20970], [50657, 50658]],
          18: [[41939, 41940], [101315, 101317]],
          19: [[83878, 83881], [202631, 202634]],
          20: [[167757, 167763], [405263, 405269]]
        };

        var imageMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
          getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) {
            if (zoom < 17 || zoom > 20 ||
                bounds[zoom][0][0] > coord.x || coord.x > bounds[zoom][0][1] ||
                bounds[zoom][1][0] > coord.y || coord.y > bounds[zoom][1][1]) {
              return null;
            }

            return ['//www.gstatic.com/io2010maps/tiles/5/L2_',
                zoom, '_', coord.x, '_', coord.y, '.png'].join('');
          },
          tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
        });

        map.overlayMapTypes.push(imageMapType);
      }
```

I am not what is **bounds** array.

Google has documentation but it's harder for me to understand this map type.  can anyone explain it.

I have **4 points** with lat-lng. how to overlay image within these points?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided example `bounds` array represents *tiles coordinates* per a zoom level. Tile coordinates are used to reference map tiles which contains the imagery for any given point. Refer [the official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/coordinates#tile-coordinates) for a more details. Tile coordinates could be converted into latitiude/longitude and vice versa, for example:

```
var imageMapType = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {

        var scale = Math.pow(2, zoom);
        var prj = map.getProjection();
        var worldCoordinate = new google.maps.Point(coord.x * this.tileSize.width / scale,coord.y * this.tileSize.height / scale);
        var latLng = prj.fromPointToLatLng(worldCoordinate);
        console.log(latLng.toString());

        if (zoom < 17 || zoom > 20 ||
            bounds[zoom][0][0] > coord.x || coord.x > bounds[zoom][0][1] ||
            bounds[zoom][1][0] > coord.y || coord.y > bounds[zoom][1][1]) {
            return null;
        }

        var tileUrl = ['//www.gstatic.com/io2010maps/tiles/5/L2_',
            zoom, '_', coord.x, '_', coord.y, '.png'].join('');

        return tileUrl;
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256)
});
```

where

`coord` and `zoom` - tile coordinates and the zoom level of image tile

The following options could be considered to overlay an image onto the map.

**Option 1. Using Custom Map Types**

To generate map tiles from an image [MapTiler](http://www.maptiler.com/) could be utilized as demonstrated below.

Image

[image]

Bounds `(South: 62.281819, West: -150.287132, North: 62.400471, East: -150.005608)`

Result

[image]

**Option 2. Using Custom Overlays**

Overlays are objects on the map that are tied to latitude/longitude coordinates, so they move when you drag or zoom the map. [This example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple) show how to creates a custom overlay containing a image of the relevant area on the map.